# How can i go through this json in java?

Tags: java, android, json, api

I am working on an Android project, in which I am using Volley to consume an Api. The query is being done correctly and the next JSON returns to me. I am trying to access the elements of this jsonArray in java

```
[
    {
        "Estado": 1,
        "_id": "5dfd27fb971f730f31cc12d5",
        "empresas": "5dfbeec1f87e0e3030b38143",
        "Codigo": "1001AZXL001",
        "Codigo_Barras": "7702345654127",
        "Descripcion": "JEAN talla XL ",
        "Detalles": [
            {
                "_id": "5dfd27fb971f730f31cc12d7",
                "bodegas": "5dfd2383971f730f31cc12cf",
                "Cantidad": 6,
                "Precio": 150000,
                "Unidad_Medida": "UND"
            },
            {
                "_id": "5dfd27fb971f730f31cc12d6",
                "bodegas": "5dfd23b7971f730f31cc12d0",
                "Cantidad": 15,
                "Precio": 150000,
                "Unidad_Medida": "UND"
            }
        ],
        "Talla": "XL",
        "Color": "AZ",
        "Minimo": 5000,
        "Maximo": 30000,
        "Fecha_Creacion": "2019-12-20T19:58:51.720Z"
    }
]
```

For that I am using the following code

```
 public void onResponse(JSONArray jsonArray) {

                         for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                                try {
                                    JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                    descripcionProducto = jsonObject.getString("Descripcion");
                                    tallaProducto = jsonObject.getString("Talla");
                                    txtDescripcion.setText(descripcionProducto);
                                    txtUnidades.setText(tallaProducto);

                                }
                                catch(JSONException e) {

                                }
                            }
                        }
```

But I cannot access the elements that are inside the "Detalles" object

Comment: What do you mean when you say that you "cannot access the elements"?  How are you trying to access them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following :

```
public void onResponse(JSONArray jsonArray) {

 for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            descripcionProducto = jsonObject.getString("Descripcion");
            tallaProducto = jsonObject.getString("Talla");
            txtDescripcion.setText(descripcionProducto);
            txtUnidades.setText(tallaProducto); 

            JSONArray array  = jsonObject.getJSONArray("Detalles")
            for(int j = 0; j < array.length() ; ++j){
            try{
              JSONObject jsonObject2 = array.getJSONObject(j);
              //ACCESS THE PARAMETERS OF detalles HERE FOR EX :
              String bodegas = jsonObject2.getString("bodegas");
               }catch(JSONException e) {}
           }

        }
        catch(JSONException e) {

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is another Jsonarray, if you want to get the data inside, you Need to get the Jsonarray and read the data from there.

```
JSONArray array  = jsonObject.getJSONArray("Detalles")
```

If you want the Data inside this Array you can Access them as you already did